Creating a short, d-dense list of points on the sphere S^4 in Python
I am a mathematician and this is my first time using Stack Overflow, sorry if the question is not adequate or there is some better place to ask this.  I would like to know if there is a standard way to do the following. Let d be some small distance (e.g. d=0.03).
I want to create in Python a list L of points of the sphere S^4, so each point is a vector like [0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0], such that every point of S^4 is at distance <d of some point of L. I also need the list to not be very long, it should not have more than 10^8 points (I guess that means that I cannot expect this to work for d<0.02 aprox).
The most important thing is that we are absolutely sure that any point of S^4 is at distance <d of some point of L, as I plan to use this list in a mathematical proof if it ends up being feasible. I have seen other questions but they either did not adress this point or they are for the 2-dimensional sphere S^2.
I have some ideas for how to create the list (e.g. take evenly spaced points in the boundary of the cube [-1,1]^5 and then project them to S^4) but they seem like they would be pretty inefficient and I would end up with at least twice as many points as necessary so I will not get a value of d as small as possible. Maybe some approach based on triangulating the sphere could be more efficient, but I am not sure how to implement that. To sum up, I just want to know if someone has already optimized this process.

How a programmer would tackle this is probably quite different from how a mathematician would tackle this. If you want something you can use in a mathematical proof, you are probably looking for theoretical solution rather than a practical approximation. Math exchange might be a better place for this question therefore. My thoughts were to figure out how I would approach this for an ordinary 3D sphere first then try to adapt it to higher dimensions. I thought maybe you could start with a regular polyhedron like an icosahedron, then decide where the points should go in each tetrahedral section.

You would then need to deform the distribution a bit, but you should be able to come up with a formula for how the separations change. Then try the same thing with whatever is an appropriate hyper-polyhedra or whatever they are called. Just an idea.

On S^2 I would subdivide the icosahedron and project.  This is efficient, because the icosahedron is close to the sphere and the angles of the faces don't change much in projection.  I'll try to think of a similar subdivision of simplices on S^4, but you'd probably get there before me.

I see. Maybe I'll try some simplicial subdivision in the end

Saúl, looks like you are getting some good suggestions here, but you might want to check math.stackexchange.com for this or other problems; this problem seems to be mostly conceptual in nature so math.SE might be a good fit.

Here's a simple recursive solution that meets your criteria.
In greater than 2 dimensions, it quantizes the first dimension into an approximately optimal number of points evenly spaced along the arc, and then at each point recursively solves 1 fewer dimensions.
At 2 dimensions it just subdivides the circle.
For any point on S^4, you can find the closest point in the solution by just quantizing the first 3 coordinates and then finding the closest point on the remaining circle.
I get < 37M points for d=0.03
import math

# count required points on unit n-1-sphere
def countPoints(dims, dmax):
    if dims > 2:
        # for more than 2 dimensions, subdivide the first
        # one into equal arc lengths and recurse.
        # max distance to point in first dimension
        # d0^2 * dims = dmax^2
        d0 = math.sqrt((dmax * dmax)/dims)
        divisions = math.ceil(math.pi*0.5/d0)
        d0 = math.pi*0.5/divisions
        # remaining distance for other dimensions
        # d0^2 + dleft^2 = dmax^2
        dleft = math.sqrt(dmax*dmax - d0*d0)
        total = 0
        theta = d0 - math.pi*0.5
        while theta < math.pi*0.5:
            # radius in remaining dimensions at point x=sin(theta)
            rleft = math.cos(theta)
            total += countPoints(dims-1, dleft/rleft)
            theta += d0*2
        return total
    # in 2 dimensions, just subdivide the circle
    if dmax > 2:
        return 1
    if dmax > math.sqrt(2):
        return 2
    return math.ceil(math.pi/dmax)

print(countPoints(5, 0.03))


Thanks for the answer. Although this code wouldn't count any points with first coordinate strictly between $-1$ and $-1+0.03/√5$, right? If I understood correctly. This would mean that it only counts one point at distance $<0.1$ of $[1,0,0,0,0]$, so it cannot contain points at distance $<0.03$ of any point in $\mathbb{S}^4$

You're right.  I fixed it by subdividing the early dimensions into equal arc lengths on the sphere.  Point count goes up to 36M

You can also use the Sobol sequence to generate the points:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import qmc


def _sobol(n):
    pool = qmc.Sobol(d=5).random_base2(m=int(np.log2(n)))
    pool = (2 * pool) - 1
    norm = np.linalg.norm(pool, axis=1)
    return pool / norm[:, None]


def _close_points(P, d):
    for i in range(len(P)):
        flag = False
        for j in range(i + 1, len(P)):
            if np.linalg.norm(P[i] - P[j]) < d:
                flag = True
                break
        if not flag:
            return False
    return True


s = _sobol(2 ** 12)
print(_close_points(s, 0.4))


Prints
[[ 0.68263768 -0.07988265  0.42541596 -0.12742955 -0.57481087]
 [-0.68934057  0.23340231 -0.55383133  0.33563861  0.22572223]
 [-0.24480291 -0.49381149  0.27896546 -0.52489962  0.58555991]
 ...
 [-0.5374891   0.32468645 -0.02446971  0.63182053  0.45374907]
 [-0.52988716 -0.37052085  0.37862191 -0.43598841  0.49849118]
 [ 0.53466745  0.53872074 -0.54654737  0.35285128 -0.02631777]]


True



To have all the points within a distance, we obviously need more points, or a larger distance.
This generator is more efficient that other random generators for generating the points.


Thanks, I will take a look. This algorithm seems to ensure that the points are equidistributed in the sphere in some sense, but I would need to check whether it really ensures that there are points close enough to any point in the sphere

@SaúlRM That's right. You need to generate a minimum number of points based on the d and it would work, so that you don't have to double check. You can double check it with _close_points (), but that's an expensive check. It'd be just easier to generate more points.
